# Read line issue

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script which need to look into a lst file and read the line and print the line if there is nothing left in the list it need to exit the script but the below script is looping itself and the lst file has two numbers(man,san).

```
vi do.lst 
man
san
```

code:=

```
  cat /ora/do.lst
  while read -r line
  do
   if [[ -z $line ]]
     then
         echo "The list is empty "
          exit
  else
      lst_no=${line},
      echo "${line} is processing now "
  fi
  done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything looks fine, you just need to pipe a `cat` into the loop:

```
cat /ora/do.lst |  while read -r line
  do
   if [[ -z $line ]]
     then
       echo "The list is empty "
       exit
     else
      lst_no=${line},
      echo "${line} is processing now "
   fi
done
```

This is obviously not the optimal way to process lines, but I assume it's just for learning purpose.

---

A little better would be to at least avoid useless `cat` and unnecessary pipe:

```
while read -r line; do
...
done </ora/do.lst
```

or even better, to preserve stdin for commands inside loop:

```
while read -r line <&3; do
...
done 3</ora/do.lst
```

However, if your file has many lines you may want to consider rewriting the script in `awk`, `perl` or other tool dedicated for text-processing task. Shell loops are not optimized in this regards.

Comment: can i get the optmised way to do it ?

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku but what are you trying to achieve? Adding "processing now" to each non-empty line in the file doesn't sound the real goal.

Comment: NO!!  i am appending that line to a variable to use across my shell script thats my goal.

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku A shell loop is not best tool to processing files, but if your file has just few lines then optimization doesn't really matter. If there are thousands or millions then first of all remove `cat`  and a pipe and instead add redirection `</ora/do.lst` just after final  `done`. However real benefit would come with rewriting whole script in dedicated processing tool, like `awk`, `perl` or the like.

Comment: I've never seen a while beginning in a pipe. Ugly. You could've at least showed him the redirecting solution.